# Algorithm to distribute drives among multiple datastores

Tags: algorithm, filesystems, vmware

I am trying to build a virtual server. I am going to take the filesystems that the server needs and put them on a datastore. However if that datastore does not have the capacity to support all of the filesystems then I want to play them on different datastores. For example:

Filesystems:

```
C: 50 gig
D: 75 gig
E: 100 gig
```

If I find a datastore that has the free space to hold 225 gig of storage called LUN001 then I want to select that datastore and be done with it. However if there are not datastores that can support that size then I want to split the filesystems among multiple like:

```
C: 50 gig on LUN001 (70 gig free)
D: 75 gig on LUN025 (90 gig free)
E: 100 gig on LUN031 (125 gig free)
```

I want to place the largest drives first in case I can place the smaller ones later on. Does anyone know of an algorithm like this or know how to easily produce one?

thanks,

Comment: Someone may provide you with an algorithm, but you'll likely  have better luck if you post your attempts to create one.

Comment: "Place the largest remaining filesystem on the datastore with the greatest free space; repeat until you run out of something." That is one algorithm. If you want something more efficient, you might study [the Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).